# Validating value for Correct format

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic

I have number of textboxes and it's format should be  XXX.XX where X could be any number user enters. I have a submit button also. So, before submitting it is necessary that if a textbox is having a value it should follow the given format.
I m proceeding like below. Below is a code + steps  that I want:::

I have to loop thorough the div element an detect each textbox and then for each textbox if it have a value, I have to validate it .

```
 <div id="DivFeeContent" style="float: left; width: 100%;">
         <input type="text" style="width: 95px;" maxlength="3"  class="validate" />
         <input type="text" style="width: 95px;" maxlength="3"  class="validate" />
         <input type="text" style="width: 95px;" maxlength="3"  class="validate" />
         <input type="text" style="width: 95px;" maxlength="3"  class="validate" />
</div>
```

Code

```
function CheckpricePrice() {
    $("#DivFeeContent input:text").each(function () {
         var Value= $(this).val();
         if(Value!='')
          {
                // Check the Format . It should be XXX.XX
                  if (Value == matches)
                  {
                   }
                   else{ return false;}   
          }

         });

     Here Goes Submission of the form
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use RegEx:

```
if(/^\d+\.\d{2}$/.test(Value))
{
      //valid number
}
```

which basically means match any number with 2 digits after dot, so XXXXX.XX or XXX.XX will work. If you only want XXX.XX then you'd update the pattern to be like `/^\d{3}\.\d{2}$/`